# Selecting data from two table with condition

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables

```
1. studentprofile

sud_id   name

1         kp

2         kishan

3          raj



2. fee_generate

fee_id    stud_id    fee_balance  name

1            1         0           kp

2            2         10          kishan
```

I want to show those students whose fee is not submitted  or have any balance, which means that I want to show is as following

> kishan  and  raj

I am not able to write the query with any join. My second problem is that name columns are common in both tables.
So the selected name column should come from `studentprofile` table and order by name from `studentprofile` table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to left join the fee_generate table on the student_profile table and include those records where the fee_generate.student_id is null (not submitted) or the balance is over 0:

```
select s.* from student_profile s
left join fee_generate f on s.stud_id=f.stud_id
where f.stud_id is null or f.balance>0
order by f.name
```